Copilot availability on SKU's below F64
I saw that to get Copilot, at least the preview, for Fabric, we should have a minimum of F64.
Is it true for GA as well or will Copilot be available at lower SKUs (F32) at that time ?
Another question, apart from Copilot and ability to publish reports which can be viewed by free users, are there other features which are available with F64 and above, which are not available at lower tiers ?

Copilot is available only for F64 and above (P1 and above for Power BI Premium).
Another point is that Copilot experience in Microsoft Fabric is still in Public Preview, even though Fabric as a product is GA'ed
